# Trigger controller function

Tags: model-view-controller, extjs

I can't get the `onClick` to fire.

Here's a fiddle https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/3e3h

Can someone see what I'm not getting right?

Answer (score 1):

You can use tap event, something like this:

```
Ext.define('Fiddle.controller.GenerateReportButton', {
    extend:'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.generatereportbutton',

    onClick: function() {
        console.log('Click!')
    }
})

Ext.define('Fiddle.GenerateReportButton', {
    extend: 'Ext.Button',
    xtype: 'generatereportbutton',
    controller: 'generatereportbutton',
    listeners: {
        tap: 'onClick'
    }
})

Ext.create({
    xtype: 'generatereportbutton',
    itemId: 'mybutton',
    text: 'Trigger',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
});
```